# how to run a form with parameter in codeigniter?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, web-services, soap

I am new to codeigniter and i want to run my sms web service code in view when user insert number.
but the post method is empty! can anyone help me?

```
var_dump($_POST['sendSms']);exit;
            if(array_key_exists('sendSms', $_POST)) {
                sendSms();
            }
function sendSms(){ //my sms web service code}
echo '<form  method="Post" action= "http://crm.oynarco.ir/admin/settings?group=sms">';
            ?>
            <input type="hidden" 
              name="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name()?>" 
              value="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash()?>">
            <?php
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="username" value="09172030433"/><br />';
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="password" value="Oynar1234" /><br />';
            echo '<input type="text" name="to" class="form-control test-phone" placeholder="'._l('staff_add_edit_phonenumber').'" /><br />';
            echo '<textarea type="text" name="text" class="form-control sms-gateway-test-message" placeholder="'._l('test_sms_message').'" ></textarea><br />';
            echo '<input type="text" name="From" class="form-control" value="5000203069627" /><br />';
            echo '<input type ="submit" name="sendSms" class="btn btn-info send-test-sms" value="'._l('send_test_sms').'" />';
            echo '</form>';
```

Comment: Having even hidden fields on a form with some information is a big risk.  It's easy to view the source and see what it's using.  Also (depending on how you use it) this information can still be changed or faked by users who wish to exploit your site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in action root to controller then in controller get the post method and add your sms function.

```
?>
            <form  method="Post" action= "settings/sendSms">
            <input type="hidden" 
              name="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name()?>" 
              value="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash()?>">
            <?php
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="username" value = "09172030433"/><br />';
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="password" value ="Oynar1234" /><br />';
            echo '<input type="text" name="to" class="form-control test-phone" placeholder="'._l('staff_add_edit_phonenumber').'" /><br />';
            echo '<textarea type="text" name="text" class="form-control sms-gateway-test-message" placeholder="'._l('test_sms_message').'" ></textarea><br />';
            echo '<input type="text" name="From" class="form-control" value = "5000203069627" /><br />';
            echo '<input type ="submit" name="sendSms" class="btn btn-info send-test-sms" value = "'._l('send_test_sms').'" />';
            echo '</form>';
```

in controller:

```
public function sendSms(){
    //var_dump($_POST);exit;
    if (isset($_POST) ){
        //send sms
    }
```